# SQL param in WHERE clause to fetch NULL value

Tags: sql, null, where-clause, param

```
Declare @param char(1)
SET @param = 'A'
```

@param can be 'A','B' or 'C'

```
SELECT x, y FROM myTbl
WHERE y = @param
```

if @param = 'A' or 'B' then y = @param works fine
if @param  = 'C' then I want to WHERE to fetch the rows where y IS NULL

I could achieve this using dynamic sql but can't figure out how to do it without dynamic sql. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use basic boolean logic:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM myTbl
WHERE y = @param or (@param = 'C' and y is null);
```

If you really want to be more explicit:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM myTbl
WHERE (@param <> 'C' AND y = @param) OR
      (@param = 'C' AND y IS NULL);
```